# UDL driver not creating dev/fb0 on kernel 5.10

Tags: video, linux-kernel, debian, udl

i am running 5.10 kernel with debian bookworm on an arm.

i want to use a usb 2.0 hdmi adaptor.

i have both udl and the udlfb drivers set to modules in kernel.

with no blacklisting the udlfb driver loads and creates an fb0 device but no dri/card0 device.

when i black list udlfb, the udl driver gets loaded and i get dev dri card0, but i dont get an fb0 device.

fyi, i have no other displays/graphics card on the embedded device.

on different ubuntu pcs i see the udl or drm create the card0 AND fb0 devices.

am i missing something in my kernel config that isnt allowing fb0 to get made?
i see no errors when plugging in the adaptor, just my output on dmesg is one line short that what i see on other systems and thats the creation on fb0.

i did install xorg.
i do not want a desktop manager only xorg so that i can just play a video and nothing else.

it plays with just the udlfb driver but is very slow, like 1 fps.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

fixed issue.

was missing this kernel config parameter
CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_EMULATION

it now works as expected.